What is this book about faeries?
It was about a girl who didn’t realise she had water faerie powers but found out that she did and hid it from her dad. She went to these meetings or school to learn how to use her powers. The book changed its name when it became a series.

Welcome to SciFi.SE! When did you read this? Why did she hide the powers from her dad? Who taught her about her powers initially?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.
